# WScript.Shell.Run() Return values 255 on Win 7 x86 (Korean) OS

Tags: vbscript

In a vbscript file I use `WScript.Shell.Run(vcredist.exe, 0, TRUE)` to execute vcredist.exe, but such function returns a value of 255. It fails to run vcredist.exe on Win-7 x86 bit korean os. I use vcredist version 9 Reference url:[microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368).

Comment: This What happens if you run it outside of VBScript?  Same result?  This isn't a programming issue.  Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: vcredist installed successfully if it installed without VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Check if vcredist if compatible with your os , Try running it with 1 instead and check if things go properly . if not then maybe there is a compatibility issue or incomplete file .. Hope it helps

Comment: vcredist installed successfully, if try to install alone (without using vbscript) on Win-7 x86 bit korean os.

Comment: vcredist installed successfully if it installed without VBScript.

Comment: I opened vcredist.exe in Hexedit then it is observe that such program can not be run in DOS mode. but it is not realize that Win-7 X86 (korean os) failed to execute vcredist.exe version on Win- 7 X86(Korean os). Following code use read from binary file binaryRecord.ReadStream(2, binaryRecord.DataSize(2), msiReadStreamAnsi)